# Pop() function for stack in C

Tags: c, pointers, stack

I've been trying for some time now to make my pop() function work properly but some strange reason all it does is... nothing.
Here is my Stack declaration & function.L.E. I also added the push function.

```
typedef struct node
{
    int v;
    struct node* next;
}Node;

void push(Node **l,int val)
{
    Node *p = (Node *)calloc(1,sizeof(Node));
    p->v = val;
    Node *aux=*l;
    if(aux == NULL)
    {
        *l = p;
        return;
    }
    while(aux->next != NULL)
        aux = aux->next;
    aux->next = p;
}

void pop(Node **l)
{
  if(*l != NULL)
  {
    Node *aux,*prev;
    prev = *l;
    aux = prev->next;
    if(aux == NULL)
      free(prev);
    else
    {
      while(aux->next != NULL)
      {
         prev = aux;
         aux = aux->next;
      }
      prev->next = NULL;
      free(aux);
    }
  }
}
```

And I call it with

```
Node *stack = NULL;
pop(&stack);
```

Comment: It does nothing because you told the function to return if the value passed in is equal to `NULL`

Comment: @self argue please. Btw I removed that part and it still does not work

Comment: This is not your problem, but why are you calling `free` on `prev->v` and `aux->v`? The `v` member isn't declared as a pointer to anything; are you assigning the result of `malloc` or `calloc` to it?

Comment: @JohnBode No , I'm not. You are right. I removed it. But it still does not work properly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would help to see how you push items onto the stack.  If you're really calling `pop` without a `push` first, well, then it's not *supposed* to do anything, is it?

This bit makes me nervous:

```
Node *aux,*prev;
prev = *stack;
aux = prev->next;
if(aux == NULL)
{
    free(prev);
    return;
}
```

You set `prev` to `*stack`, and if nothing follows `prev`, you free it.  Note that since `prev == *stack`, you've also freed `*stack`, so that pointer is now *invalid*.  If you try to access that pointer in your caller, you'll invoke Undefined Behavior.

It looks like you're making your list tail the top of the stack; I'm going to tell you right now that you will make your life *much* simpler if you make the list *head* the top of the stack, such that your pushes and pops look like the following:

```
bool push( Node **l, int val )
{
  Node *p = calloc( 1, sizeof *p );
  if ( p )
  {
    p->v = val;
    p->next = *l;   // set p to point to the current head of the list
    *l = p;         // make p the new head of the list
  }
  return p != NULL;  // will return false if the calloc (and by extenion,
}                    // the push operation) fails.  

bool pop( Node **l, int *v )
{
  Node *p = *l;      // p points to head of list
  if ( !p )
    return false;

  *v = p->val;     // get value in current node
  *l = p->next;    // make the next element the new list head
  p->next = NULL;  // sever the old list head
  free( p );       // and deallocate it

  return true;
}
```

No list traversals, no need to keep track of current and previous nodes.  All you care about is the head node.  The statement `p->next = NULL;` isn't strictly necessary since we immediately free `p` afterwards.  I like it because it makes it obvious that we have *removed* `p` from the list, but if you don't want to spare the cycles, you can omit it.

**Edit**

I was right to be nervous about that code.

So here's basically what's happening - when you have exactly one item in the stack, you free the head of the list, **but you don't update the value of the list pointer** (`*stack` in the original code, `*l` in the latest edit).  The value of the `stack` variable in `main` is unchanged, and now it's *invalid* - the memory at that address is no longer allocated.  So the next time you call `push`, it sees that `*l` is not `NULL`, and attempts to traverse down the (non-existent) list.

At this point the behavior is undefined; literally *anything* can happen.  On my system after the first `push`, `stack` has the value `0x501010`.  I do a `pop`, which `free`s that memory, but doesn't change the value of `stack`.  On the next `push`, `*l` is not `NULL`, so I set `(*l)->next` to whatever `malloc` returns, which in my case is...`0x501010` again.  So `*l` is `0x501010`, and `(*l)->next` is `0x501010`.  If I try to push another item, I wind up in an infinite loop (`p` == `p->next`).

To fix this, you need to set the list pointer to `NULL` after you `free` it:

```
Node *aux,*prev;
prev = *l;
aux = prev->next;
if(aux == NULL)
{
    free(prev);
    *l = NULL;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help John.I thought that using that chunk of code that you highlighted from my code will just free my stack..I did not know that this could cause "undefined behavior"...I completely forgot to paste the push function, sorry for that(I edited now). I knew about this technique that you showed me but I AM stubborn to find why it does not work the way I've tried. If you have time to at least give me a hint I would be even more grateful.

Comment: @CostiIvan: You say the `pop` function doesn't do anything; as written, it doesn't return any value or write any output to the console, so how are you determining that it isn't doing anything?  Are you tracing the execution with a debugger?  Are you checking the value of the `stack` pointer in whatever called `pop`?

Comment: I am checking the value whenever pop is called, yes. E.g. If I have 1 value in stack and I use pop() I either get that exatcly value, or a random value. If I have >1 value using pop() has no effect...

Comment: John.... thank you a lot for taking the time to help me figure things out. Now I understand. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Asterisks makes me nervous. without you guys I'd live in a cave.